# Can Angular 8 formgroup binding to dropdown options?

Tags: angular, angular-material, formgroups

I have a nested formgroup like below

```
  studentForm = this.formBuilder.group({
    Score: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.max(100), Validators.min(0)])],
    license: this.formBuilder.group({
       chineseName: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(100)])],
       englishName: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(100)])],
    });
  });
```

The studentForm contains a score and license, one student has one license

i made the license formgroup binding to angular material select like below

```
 <form [formGroup]="studentForm ">
        <mat-form-field>
          <mat-label>license</mat-label>
          <mat-select formControlName="license">
            <mat-option *ngFor="let option of licenses" [value]="option">
              {{option.chineseName}},{{option.englishName}}
            </mat-option>
          </mat-select>
        </mat-form-field>
</form>
```

but i'll get this error

```
StudentComponent.html:9 ERROR TypeError: control.registerOnChange is not a function
    at setUpModelChangePipeline (forms.js:2701)
    at setUpControl (forms.js:2580)
    at FormGroupDirective.addControl (forms.js:6318)
    at FormControlName._setUpControl (forms.js:6969)
    at FormControlName.ngOnChanges (forms.js:6892)
    at checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline (core.js:24499)
    at checkAndUpdateNodeInline (core.js:35163)
    at checkAndUpdateNode (core.js:35102)
    at debugCheckAndUpdateNode (core.js:36124)
    at debugCheckDirectivesFn (core.js:36067)
```

is it possible to bind formgroup to dropdown list?

thanks everyone

Comment: `license` is declared as a form group in your code, that's why it doesn't work. Otherwise, yes, it's possible, like any other control.

Comment: @Maryannah so what can i do to solve this problem?

Comment: Declare it as a control `license: ['' [Validators.xxx(), Validators.xxx()]]`

Comment: @Maryannah but i have two property in lincense. control only contain one property

Comment: Split it on value change or before sending your data. Or create two drop-down lists.

Comment: @Maryannah thanks you